# Kotlin sharedflow with lambda

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I try to understand how/why it works.

I have such flow

```
var flow: MutableSharedFlow<**() -> Unit**>
```

type is lambda, without arguments and return type is Unit.
I have a few methods

```
fun foo()
 fun foo2(arg: SomeClass)
```

Next i send into this flow

```
flow.tryEmit { foo() }
```

So the foo() is method which can be transformed to appropriate lambda ()->Unit

But when i send

```
flow.tryEmit { foo2(arg) }
```

It works too. But actually i send lambda with type (SomeClass)->Unit

I don't understand why it works?

Comment: `{ foo2(arg) }` is still of type `() -> Unit`. The lambda does not take a parameter, it only captures `arg` from an enclosing scope. If it was `{ arg -> foo2(arg) }`, then it would be of type `(SomeClass) -> Unit`.

Comment: Also, you might prefer to use function references: `flow.tryEmit(::foo)` would work, `flow.tryEmit(::foo2)` would not, because `::foo2` has type `(SomeClass) -> Unit`.

Comment: @marstran if i understand you correctly, { } - this is the lambda and foo2(arg) - her body?

Comment: @Lavan Correct, the braces denote the lambda expression.

Answer (score 2):

First, for clarification, "lambda" isn't a type. It's a syntax for expressing a function. You have a MutableSharedFlow of *functions*, not of *lambdas* specifically. When you call a function that takes a function as a parameter, like `tryEmit()` does when the flow type is a function, then you have several options for expressing that function.

- A lambda
- A functional reference (`::` before an existing function, or simply passing a property/variable name that is pointing at a function).
- An [anonymous function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#anonymous-functions)

For a lambda, the content expressed between `{` and `}` is called every time the lambda function is invoked. This is what your example is using, with [trailing lambda syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), that is, no parentheses around the function argument. `tryEmit { foo() }` is a shortened form of `tryEmit({ foo() })`, which might make it clearer to you what you are passing as an argument. What you have here is a function (the lambda) wrapping a function call (calling `foo()`).

When you use `tryEmit { foo2(arg) }`, this is still a lambda with no argument (a function wrapping a function call). The `arg` is part of what you are using each time to invoke the lambda function. If `arg` is a `var` or a property, the reference gets "captured" by the lambda so it can be invoked every time the lambda is invoked. This is important to be aware of because it can be a source of memory leaks.